# Trusting unknown certificates in windows store app

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a windows store app I am trying to connect to a api using this code

```
try {
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient {
    BaseAddress = Constants.baseAddress
}) {
        using(var content = new StringContent(DataToSend, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")) {
           using(var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("oauth2/token", content)) {...
        }...
    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {...
}
```

but I am getting this exception:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

and in the InnerException

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I've been told I need to trust unknown certificates.
How can I do that on windows store app ?